# Measuring 12V car battery voltage precisely from the output of an ideal diode controller

Tags: automotive, voltage-measurement

[image: Circuit schematic of power input section]

I'm designing a device that will be plugged into the OBD2-port.
One of the features is reading the battery voltage on demand directly from the diagnostics port.

In order to protect the device from a reverse-polarity condition (edit: e.g. connecting the battery backwards), I'm including a MOSFET driven by an ideal diode controller.

The LM74700 controller controls the gate of the MOSFET to regulate the forward voltage drop at 20 mV during nominal load currents. During forward "Regulated Conduction Mode" the anode to cathode voltage can be between 0-50mV (light and higher load currents, respectively).

I figured I could use a precise digital power monitor like the INA226 to measure the battery voltage. However, the Vbus pin only withstands up to -0.3V, so no reverse-polarity protection built-in  to measure directly from the input voltage.
To overcome this, I thought about reading the voltage right after the MOSFET instead.

My circuit will draw from 0.1 to 0.3A at the input supply voltage.
Do you think choosing the right MOSFET (Rdson) will allow a constant 20mV a-k regulation so as to be able to negate this inserted error?
The datasheet states that the Regulated Forward V(AK) Threshold is between 13 to 29mV though, so that's at least a 16mV discrepancy.

Anyway, do you know of any ICs to monitor voltage precisely with reverse polarity protection? 5mV accuracy would be nice, without a complex design with discrete parts.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How you would manage to connect a OBD2 connector the wrong way is beyond me. I guess you need reverse polarity protection.

Comment: The force required to insert and OBD2 connector in a wrong way will destroy you electronics anways.... Dont over-engineer your device - KISS. TVS and decoupling is well appreciated, but i would drop reverse protection.

Comment: There are some pretty extensive white papers (like this one: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2689-protection-of-automotive-electronics-from-electrical-hazards-guidelines-for-design-and-component-selection-stmicroelectronics.pdf) that go over the - not to use an overly technical term - gross electrical environment expected in an automotive application. I agree with the other commenters that connecting the circuit backwards isn't a plausible situation, but brief reverse polarity spikes are probably something to look out for.

Comment: @MiNiMe As easily as connecting the battery backwards. Or reversed jump wires.